# Use parametrized quantum circuit output amplitudes for training in tensorflow

Tags: programming, quantum-circuit, cirq, tfq

I am trying to train a quantum neural network in tensorflow_quantum (tfq). Using `cirq.Circuit` I have set up my circuit. I now need to wrap it in a keras model for training. For this I must embed the circuit in a `tfq.layers.PQC` layer (according to the documentation: "this layer is for training parameterized quantum models"). However, when using PQC, I must specify a value for the parameter `operators`, which must be a `cirq.PauliSum` or Python `list` of `cirq.PauliSum` objects. I am unsure how to obtain the amplitudes via these kind of operators, but since I am dealing with a simulator I think it should not be necessary. Is there a way to train my circuit using the amplitudes of the circuit output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tfq.layers.State()` you can directly access the state amplitudes and you do not need operators.